# Relation between Lebesgue and Riemann Integration for real-valued functions of a p-adic variable and the like

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, harmonic-analysis, riemann-sum

Let $p$ be an odd prime, let $\mathbb{Z}_{2,p}$ denote $\mathbb{Z}_{2}\times\mathbb{Z}_{p}$, let $dx$ and $dy$ be the Haar probability measures on $\mathbb{Z}_{2}$ and $\mathbb{Z}_{p}$, respectively,  and consider a function $F:\mathbb{Z}_{2,p}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ in $L^{1}\left(\mathbb{Z}_{2,p}\right)$.

The Fubini-Tonelli Theorem for abstract measure spaces tells us that the integrability of $F$ is sufficient to guarantee the existence of:  $$G\left(y\right)=\int_{\mathbb{Z}_{2}}F\left(x,y\right)dx$$
for almost every $p$-adic integer $y$. Moreover, $G$ is in $L^{1}\left(\mathbb{Z}_{p}\right)$.

Using the translation-invariance of the Haar measure, I can prove that:

$$\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\int_{\mathbb{Z}_{2}}\frac{1}{2^{N}}\sum_{n=0}^{2^{N}-1}F\left(2x+n,y\right)dx=\int_{\mathbb{Z}_{2}}\left(\int_{\mathbb{Z}_{2}}F\left(2x+z,y\right)dz\right)dx=\int_{\mathbb{Z}_{2}}\left(\int_{\mathbb{Z}_{2}}F\left(z,y\right)dz\right)dx=G\left(y\right)$$

holds for almost every $p$-adic integer $y$ in the case where $F$ is *continuous*. Does this result hold (say, by the Dominated Convergence Theorem) when $F$ is merely integrable?

Comment: $f(z) = \int_{Z_2} F(2x+z,y)dx$ is continuous (constant on $2Z_2$ and $1+2Z_2$) so everything simplifies. $\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\int_{\mathbb{Z}_{2}}\frac{1}{2^{N}}\sum_{n=0}^{2^{N}-1}F\left(2x+n,y\right)dx=\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{2^{N}}\int_{\mathbb{Z}_{2}}\sum_{n=0}^{2^{N}-1}F\left(2x+n,y\right)dx=...$

Comment: So, is the answer to my question "yes"?